# How bind CheckBox from myclass?

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, checkbox, error-handling

I want bind checkbox from my class.

but error `Text="<%=ci.CancelDetail%>"` Properties is **"This is not scriptlet. Will be output as plain text."**

Here is my code.

**HTML FROM**

```
<% foreach (ClassCancelInfo ci in ClassCancelInfo.ListCancel())
{ %>

<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk" Text="<%=ci.CancelDetail%>" />

<% } %>
```

Thanks for you time.

Comment: why you are not using checkbox list instead of this looping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this thing using looping then

following is solution:

```
<% 
 int i=0;
foreach (ClassCancelInfo ci in ClassCancelInfo.ListCancel())
{ 
%>

<input type='checkbox'  id="chk_<%=i.ToString()%>"/>
<label for="chk_<%=i.ToString()%>"><%=ci.CancelDetail%></label>
<!--<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk" Text="<%=ci.CancelDetail%>" />-->

<% i=i+1;
 } 
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `<%= ... %>` to set properties of server-side controls.

As Bhavesh suggested it's better to use [CheckboxList](http://hamidseta.blogspot.in/2011/12/checkboxlist-example-in-aspnet-c.html) and bind it with a data-source.